# awk/sed + replace only the second char with one space

Tags: linux, sed, solaris

please advice how to remove only the second "." character from the version number with awk

I need to fit the syntax for Linux & Solaris

I write the

```
  sed "s'/\./ /g'" -
```

but this syntax remove all "." from the version number

for example (version number before)

```
 34.34.55.4
```

after sed manipulation will be

```
 34.34 55.4
```

Comment: Have you considered awk instead?   Doing this with SED is going to be painful simply because it has a very limited ability to deal with any kind of state.

Comment: @Zoredache although I usually recommend awk as well, its not so painful in sed ;)

Comment: ok I update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo -e '1.2.3.4\n2.3.4\n5.6.7.8' | sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)\./\1 /'
```

The part in braces will match "something without dot, a dot, something without dot".
\1 in the replacement text will then refer to this submatch.

However, the other solution given is arguably far more elegant ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/\./ /2' <<<'34.34.55.4'
34.34 55.4
```

Comment: this syntax not work on solaris

Comment: @Eytan the `<<<'34.34.55.4'` part was just an example for input.  Simply replace it with a file name, or pipe something to it with echo.  The sed command will certainly work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU Awk`:

Command:

```
awk '$0 = gensub( /\./, " ", 2 )' <<<"34.34.55.4"
```

Output:

```
34.34 55.4
```